# Not able to create directory in ios version 8.1.3

Tags: objective-c, ios8.1

I am creating directory in document folder. It is working fine with lower versions of ios that is ios 6,7 till 8.0.

But it is creating problem in ios 8.1.3.

```
NSString *folderPath;
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *library = [path objectAtIndex:0];
folderPath = [library stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/custom"];

BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

NSLog(@"create %d",success);
```

Create returns 0 in the case of ios version 8.1.3.

Can anyone suggest something what is happening.

Comment: Try using the error, and see what you get back:
`NSError * error;
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error message: %@", error);` EDIT: I'm guessing using `withInterMediatDirectories:YES` might help;

Answer (score 1):

Error ==

2015-02-02 17:37:10.561 ALLDOX[903:51379] create Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1565f500 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/36F75DC4-C5E1-4501-A13D-0B17A3B2663E/Library/Documents/custom, NSUnderlyingError=0x1565d7b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

**I got the answer**

*Apple has changed directory path.*

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/36F75DC4-C5E1-4501-A13D-0B17A3B2663E/Library/Documents/custom   //Wrong path in ios 8.1.*

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/36F75DC4-C5E1-4501-A13D-0B17A3B2663E/Documents/custom     //Correct path for ios 8.1.*
```

Correct code for getting right directory is

```
NSString *folderPath;
folderPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/custom"];

BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

NSLog(@"create %d",success);
```

see the reference [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)